# Installing (creating?) driver for Wireless adapter

Tags: wireless, drivers

I'm very much a rookie with Linux and recently installed Ubuntu 12.04.  Now I'm trying to stall a wireless adapter, RT5370, but the instructions are completely over my head (plus certain steps like copying a file to etc/Wireless aren't working because I get a permission denied error).  Is there a simple step-by-step guide on how to install a wireless adapter???

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  echo 'install rt2800usb modprobe --ignore-install rt2800usb ; /bin/echo "148f 5370" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800usb.conf


  sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb
```

Comment: Okay.  Did that.  What next?

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1902715